# How to create an unsigned extrinsic in outer-node

Tags: extrinsic

In `substrate-node-template`, is there a way that I can use to create an extrinsic in outer-node?

I want to specifically create an unsigned extrinsic for a specific pallet call and I found this [struct](https://docs.rs/sp-runtime/latest/sp_runtime/generic/struct.UncheckedExtrinsic.html) that should do the job, but I don't know how to provide the arguments such as Call and I don't want to create an inherent, just an unsigned extrinsic for a specific pallet call.

Previously I was using `subxt` but I want to do it manually since I am in the node directly.

Answer (score 1):

Your are right to think that you need to encode the `UncheckedExtrinsic` type.

For that you need:

1. `signature`, which in your case it should be `None`.
2. A `call`, which should be the encoding of `enum RuntimeCall` in your runtime.

The easy way to find the `enum RuntimeCall` is to get it from your runtime crate. This enum is generated by `construct_runtime`. For example, in the polkadot runtime, you can see it [here](https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot/doc/polkadot_runtime/enum.RuntimeCall.html).

Comment: thanks but i could not find it! is there a specific way to retreive that enum? currently i created a runtime api that returns the unckedextrinsic unsigned extrinsic that i want

Comment: Did you see the link I posted? https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/kitchensink_runtime/enum.RuntimeCall.html Any file has `construct_runtime` has `enum RuntimeCall`.

Comment: yes i saw the link you posted and i wanted to know how to retreive that enum in my own substrate node, i tried to run cargo docs to open all the generated enums and i didn't find it

Comment: and i think a runtime api is better to be honest